# Is it possible to run one jvm on more than one pc?

Tags: java, jvm

Is there any tools that allows us to run single jvm on cluster of machines?

If no please explain why? Is it possible in theory?

Appreciate your answers.

Comment: There [was at one time](https://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/projects/systems/cjvm/).

Comment: Probably not. You need a different architectural approach. As for theory, your question is too broad for SO. Ask on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: It is possible in theory, however it is likely to be far slower in practice. Note: running a JVM across two NUMA regions in the same machine can be dramatically slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this is still a research topic. [Check here.](https://nebelwelt.net/publications/students/08ss-lee-dRVM.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually my question